# Resizing bitmap is cropping instead of scaling

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64

so I have an app that accepts user input and convert it to a bitmap image which I will scale to a fixed size before sending it over to someone else in the form of Base64 String.

The code works but whenever I attempts to resize it the image is cropped at the top left corner instead of actually scaling.

These are my codes:

```
mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap,200,300,true);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I have tried looking at [Resizing bitmap is cropping instead of scaling in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965549/resizing-bitmap-is-cropping-instead-of-scaling-in-view) and [Android - Resizing bitmap cuts it instead of scaling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393474/android-resizing-bitmap-cuts-it-instead-of-scaling-it) which has similar problems but none of the solutions actually works or they were using a workaround which resize upon drawing which I cannot use as my use case doesn't require me to draw.

I have also tried this:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

with

```
mBitmap = getResizedBitmap(mBitmap,300,200);
```

But this is also not working.

Comment: The `createScaledBitmap()` method returns the scaled Bitmap. It doesn't scale the Bitmap you pass into it.

Comment: Updated with another method which I've also tried, gives the same result, so what should I change to get it working?

Comment: Well, for the first method, I meant you should be using something like `Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap,200,300,true);`, and then encoding `scaledBitmap`, the method's return. In the second, new method, I believe you want `newWidth` and `newHeight` instead, in the `createBitmap()` call. If both of those still don't work for you, then I would create a `Canvas` for a new `Bitmap` of the desired size, and use one of the `drawBitmap()` methods with `src` and `dest` `Rect*` parameters.

Comment: Oh I get what you mean now, I did that mistake while copying the codes over, my code was actually exactly what you said it should be, Didn't work. Corrected it up there.

Comment: Well, if you're still getting the described result, then I don't think that's really the code you're running, because that'll end up with an empty, black Bitmap, since it's scaling `mBitmap`, which was just created in the previous line. (You know you can just copy and paste code from your IDE into the question.) Anyway, if you are running what I think you mean, how are you determining that the image is cropped? Are you inspecting the scaled Bitmap directly after it's scaled? Are you decoding the Base64 String, and then checking? How are you displaying the resulting image, exactly?

Comment: I was copy and pasting, only accidentally deleted something when I was deleting out comments. Anyway, I didn't get a black bitmap but I do have a feeling that I should do something in between as it's probably too fast, I am inspecting the Base64 String by the way, which works fine if I didn't try to scale it. I am supposed to send the Base64 string to a 3rd party.

Comment: The posted code doesn't really jibe with your described behavior. In the first line, you create `mBitmap` with only its dimensions and quality configuration, but no actual pixel data, which will yield a black Bitmap. Then, in the second line, `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap,200,300,true)` is returning a scaled version of that black Bitmap just created. In any case, I would suggest looking at the Bitmap directly after the `createScaledBitmap()` call to see if the problem is there, or somewhere in the Base64 encode/decode.